# VLC stream with trickplay

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player

The idea is to start a video stream from one computer and watch it on another with the ability to start/stop the stream. I think I could do this with VLC but i haven't been able to figure out how.

I've tried the following: 
(From the [official forum](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples#RTSP_live_streaming))

Stream with RTSP and RTP: 
on the server, run: 
`% vlc -vvv input_stream --sout '#rtp{dst=192.168.0.12,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp}'`

on the client(s), run: 
`% vlc rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp`

But this doesn't give me the ability to start/stop the stream from the client. 
According to the VLC release note something called "Trick play" was added in version 1.0. This seems to be what I'm looking for but i can't find any documentation that descibes how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) for remote on-demand streaming. It works very very well. Using `sshfs` you can in fact just mount the remote directory via:

```
sshfs remotemachine: /media/directory
```

and then you can **access the remote folder as a local folder**, thus you can launch `vlc`, through command line or through a file manager as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the VLC forums including the the [release notes](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/browser/NEWS?format=txt) talks about adding trickplay to the RTSP client (playback only).  I don't think that trickplay is implemented on the server yet. You may have to use a server such as [LIVE555 Media Server](http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/) to do your streaming.