# Remote edit with local editor (Linux)

Tags: linux, text-editing

I have a server I can ssh into, and I am also running Ubuntu. How do I edit this remote file using any program I have installed on my local Ubuntu, without copying it to local, editing it, and copying it back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's Ubuntu, then you probably have the full GNOME suite installed, along with GVFS – so you can access `sftp://` URLs directly in all apps.

- Use ***Places → Connect to Server*** to connect that server's filesystem as if were a local one.
- Do the same from command line using

  ```
  gvfs-mount sftp://hostname.domain.tld/
  ```

While GVFS is specific to GNOME apps, all mounted GVFS locations are accessible by *any* program via `/run/<user>/gvfs` (or `~/.gvfs/` in older versions).

KDE programs also support `sftp://` via KIO, although they don't have the equivalent of `/run/<user>/gvfs`.

Comment: Super-awesome. I never knew about this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

Try `sshfs`, a program that allows to mount a remote system accessible via ssh to a local folder.

Install it, create a mount point and execute:

```
sshfs user@host:remote_dir /path/to/mount_point
```

Now you can access the remote directory as a local one and you can use your text editor of choice.  Moreover, you can use `sshfs` as an on-demand video/music streaming solution  (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/71782/vlc-stream-with-trickplay/71852#71852)).

---

**Example:** if you want to mount the directory `music` of a user called `pippo` at host `pluto` in a folder `./pippo_music` then execute:

```
sshfs pippo@pluto:music ./pippo_music
```

You can also mount the root of the pluto host with:

```
sshfs pippo@pluto:/ ./pippo_root
```

To automate this process, add a row in `fstab`:

```
sshfs#pippo@pluto:/ /media/pippo_root fuse defaults 0 0
```

Comment: I tried to do this and edit some text files with sublime text, but it didn't work.  I could open the files, but when I hit save it wouldn't propagate back to the server.  Sometimes it would ask me for a password to save, and I'd type it in, but still no dice.

Comment: Never seen that.  Try with a different text editor.  Also, check the permissions of the file you are editing.

Answer (score 2):

Update on an old question:

KDE supports a FIle over SsH protocol called [fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol).  Basically, you open your file as URL with the fish:// scheme referring to the file. KDE copies the file over locally to a temp file as you edit. Saves and a quit will push the file back to the remote server.

e.g.

```
kate fish://user@host:/path/to/file.txt
```

There's a wrapper for non-KDE editors (or any tools):

```
kioexec other-editor-or-tool fish://user@host:/path/to/file.txt
```

Remember that you probably have the KDE libs on your machine, even if you run GNOME desktop or something else.

Comment: kate file://user@host:/path/to/file.txt is not correct. fish instead file should be used.
kate fish://user@host:/path/to/file.txt

Comment: @Matth yeah, dumb typo. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Tramp node in emacs will do this easily: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode

Comment: Damn I wish vim had `su://`

Answer (score 1):

vim can open files over SSH:

```
vim scp://myserver.com/path/to/file.txt
```